# What's the number of poker hands where one of the cards is Ace of clubs and none of the other cards can be Aces or clubs

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $5$ cards in a poker hand. Fix one of them to be Ace of clubs. Then there are $12$ ranks and $3$ suits left. First we choose $4$ ranks out $12.$ Then we choose $1$ suit out of $3$ for each chosen rank, like so: $\binom{12}4 \binom31^4$ but this doesn't agree with the given answer. What might have gone wrong?

Comment: You chose 4 out of 12. But nothing is saying that the cards are not allowed to have the same value. You could easily have the Kings of Hearts, Diamonds and Pic in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have chosen the ace of clubs, you only need to worry about picking the other 4 cards. There are $12$ other cards that are clubs in the deck which you cannot pick, and $3$ aces that are also off limits, so from $51$ cards ($52$ originally minus the ace you took) you can only pick $51-15=36$, now just pick the remaining four cards out of this bunch
$$\binom {36}{4}$$

Comment: There are $13$ cards of each rank, so there are $12$ other clubs in the deck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry, I did not remember my deck correctly, I'll edit it. Thanks.